# Edit suggested without any actual edits

Tags: bug, review, edits, suggested-edits

I [reviewed a suggested edit](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1871) but found no actual suggestion in it. Edits should have at least 6 characters changed, iirc.

There is an edit summary or comment in it, however, which is what the user should have added as the edit.

[image: edit suggestion screenshot]

Maybe this has something to do with [another bug I noticed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300007/309993) recently. Maybe this is different.

Comment: Did you check the markdown changes as well as the rendered output?

Comment: @Oded I looked at both. I have added a link. Please check it. I'm not sure what I should see there.

Comment: Think there is some bug in server side validation at some level, same as what happened in [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300007/a-funny-edit-happened-on-an-answer-today). /cc @Oded.

Comment: Did you check and see if the tags were changed?

Comment: @RichardU Nothing changed. I have linked to it in the question. :)